# Maven modules will not find dependencies with scalatest

Tags: scala, maven, configuration, scalatest

While working with scalatest I ran into a weird problem. I have a maven project with multiple modules. If I execute `mvn test` directly in the module. It works without problems, but if I do it in the root folder it complains about missing packages (dependencies) while compiling.

My configuration looks like following:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
      <artifactId>scalatest_${scala.shortversion}</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0-SNAP2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
      <artifactId>scalatest-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

plugin configuration:

```
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
            <configuration>
              <skipTests>true</skipTests>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
            <artifactId>scalatest-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <configuration>
              <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports</reportsDirectory>
              <junitxml>.</junitxml>
              <filereports>WDF TestSuite.txt</filereports>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>scala-test</id>
                <goals>
                  <goal>test</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
```

If I remove from `maven-scala-plugin` the `goals` it'll compile but scalatest will not find the test sources and exit with `No tests were executed.`:

```
        <plugin>
            <version>2.15.2</version>
            <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <goals>
                  <goal>compile</goal>
                  <goal>testCompile</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
              <scalaVersion>${scala.version}</scalaVersion>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?!

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to say without seeing all your poms, but generally speaking: 
Define in root Pom all your dependencies in *dependencyManagement* section, your plugins in *pluginManagement* section with their configuration. In child poms define only those plugins and dependencies you need.

Keep in mind that *xxxManagement* sections only build shared definition, kind of root configuration. You still have to define in *plugins* and *dependencies* sections what you need but you can omit version and configuration elements.

This will allow all your child poms to run tests in all modules.

Comment: I inherited the project and had to clean up lots of stuff. My problem was solved when I reorganized the `pluginManagement` in the root pom. Thanks for the hint!